Brake pulse before & after brake job?
2012 Chrysler 300 RWD…. My brakes were pulsing so I assumed the rotors were warped. I changed the pads and rotors (duralast / autozone OEM replacements) and cleaned the hub up with a wire brush before I put the new rotors on the hub. When I put the wheel back on I spun it and noticed that it didn’t spin completely freely. It slowed in the same part of its rotation where the rotor and pads seemed to come in contact with each other. Always touching in the same part of the rotation. I kinda assumed I didn’t completely seat the pads or something and figured the calipers would finish the job when I pushed the brakes.
Car drives fine. Brakes work fine but I do recognize pulsing continuing after the brake job and new parts. Trying to figure out why it would still be happening. No noise. Nothing fishy other than the pulsing. My gut reflex was “bad rotor” again but what are the odds a new one is bad and feels almost the same as before the brake job? What else could be the problem? FWIW, I know I have to replace the front suspension. It’s time… but I’m not sure that would produce the same rhythmic pulse that only happens during braking. Would appreciate any thoughts!

Try jacking up a wheel so it can spin, then place a box or milk crate or sawhorse (or anything) near the wheel rim where it meets the tire. Place a pencil point firmly on the box and hold it a fraction of an inch from the rim. Now spin the wheel. Do you see runout? (Wobbling?) Do this at 12:00 and 3:00 of the rim (or 6:00 / 9:00) to cover all possibilities. If you find runout, the wheel rim may be bent from hitting a pothole or curb. That will cause your brakes to pulse.

When servicing brakes or rotating tires, are you using correct tightening of wheel nuts or bolts and using correct torque on each fastener to prevent deformation of rotors that can create brake pulsing? In general, once brakes and rotors are replaced, applying brake pedal effort is better than just rotating the tire; hydraulic pressure forces calipers to center on its (greased) slide pins to align caliper over pads. Once pedal is released, tires should rotate freely with just surface friction of pads on rotors. This presumes new rotors are flat without runout (<0.002").
